# CastToBase unresolved external symbol error when using abstract class derived from WinRT Grid Class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, windows-runtime, abstract-class, c++-cx

This is something very odd I found working with C++/CX.

Given following:

```
ref class Duper : public Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Grid{
internal:
    Duper(){}
    virtual void doNothing() = 0;
public:
    virtual ~Duper(){}

};

ref class Sub : public Duper
{
internal:
    Sub(){}
    void doNothing()override{}
public:
    virtual ~Sub(){}
};
```

Calling Sub class:

```
Sub^ test = ref new Sub();
test->doNothing();
```

Works fine as expected, but when running this:

```
Sub^ test = ref new Sub();
test->Width = 20;
```

You get greeted error similar to this

```
Error   226 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Grid ^ __stdcall XSideView::__abi_CastToBase(void)" (?__abi_CastToBase@XSideView@@Q$AAGP$AAVGrid@Controls@Xaml@UI@Windows@@XZ)    D:\OZSOURCE70\OZReportViewer\OZWRTViewer\ozrv\platform.lib(OZCViewerSideView.obj)   ozrv_dll
```

You can however get around calling CastToBase by doing this:

```
Grid^ base = dynamic_cast<Grid^>(test3);
base->Width = 30;
```

And it will work fine.

Can someone please explain to me why this happens? Is there a way to fix this other than explicitly casting to Grid class every time I use this class? Although I haven't bothered to test with other ref classes, I bet they will have similar problem.

PS: It is possible this is a bug and have been fixed in later versions(I'm currently developing in Windows 8.1 with VS2013)

PPS: CastToBase documentation :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/interfacetraits-casttobase-method

Answer (score 0):

WinRT doesn't have the concept of abstract classes - that's a C++-ism. You can either use an interface (if it is 100% abstract) or make the implementation of the method(s) in your base class something like:

```
virtual void doNothing() 
{
  throw ref new Platform::FailureException(L"Can't use Duper directly"); 
}
```

(Or revert to the `dynamic_cast<>` trick).

Comment: Throwing exception on debug build was what I ended up doing since all I really wanted was to enforce future developers from overriding the method. Still, I'm a bit miffed about C++CX being not so compatible with C++ concepts.

Comment: `ref` classes have to abide by the rules of WinRT types... all your other code can be "normal" C++